# Injected object lifetime managment

Tags: c#, архитектура, inversion-of-control, ninject

Есть примерно такая ситуация, опишу сильно схематично:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
Bind<ISomeService>().To<SomeService>();

class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    public Dispose(){}
}

// Это что то вроде GodObject (прим. фасад, методы которого, дергают кнопочки из WinForms, существует пока существует форма, )
// IDisposable не реализует
class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    IUnitOfWork readonly _uow;

    public SomeService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        this._uow = uow;
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        this._uow.SomeAction1();
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        this._uow.SomeAction2();
    }
}
```

Вопрос: на сколько будет обоснованным решение сляпать безтелесную **IUnitOfWorkFactory** (Ninject.Extensions.Factory) и внедрять зависимость вместо аргумента конструктора, фабрикой, примерно следующим кодом:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();       // Здесь можно обозначить Scope, если реализации репозиториев зависят 
                                            // от DbContext, и нужно сохранять один экземпляр на весь UnitOfWork
                                            // прим: Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().DefinesNamedScope("SingleDbContextScope");
                                            // а DbContext биндить так: Bind<SomeDbContext>().ToSelf().InNamedScope("SingleDbContextScope");
Bind<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().ToFactory();
Bind<ISomeService>().To<SomeService>();

// Это что то вроде GodObject (прим. фасад, методы которого, дергают кнопочки из WinForms, существует пока существует форма, )
class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _uowFuctory;

    public SomeService(IUnitOfWorkFactory uowFuctory)
    {
        this._uowFuctory = uowFuctory;
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        using(var uow = _uowFuctory.Create())
        {
            this.uow.SomeAction1();
        }        
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        using(var uow = _uowFuctory.Create())
        {
            this.uow.SomeAction2();
        }
    }
}
```

Или же есть какие-то другие варианты решения данной проблемы, а то вроде как инъекция через фабрику, пусть и безтелесную, это совсем не ctor инъекция

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такое правило/рекомендация: ресурс должен освобождать тот, кто его создает.

Если придерживаться его, то варианта два:

- объект создается контейнером, а значит нужно использовать скоупы
- объект создается в фасаде, а значит нужно использовать фабрику и using

Если скоупы вам по какой-то причине не подходят (а их не везде можно красиво ввернуть), то фабрика -- это вполне хороший вариант. Тот факт, что вы внедряете фабрику, а не сам объект, не должен вас смущать.

Можете также рассмотреть смешанное решение: объект создается контейнером, но освобождается в фасаде. Но тут требуется имплементация `IDisposable` фасадом, которая может за собой потянуть новые вопросы, плюс появляется мешанина в стилях освобождения ресурсов. Но иногда этот вариант может быть самым дешевым.

Comment: С областями видимости и ctor injection понятно, но как быть, если TTL у SomeService  достаточно большой, как следствие у UoW локальный кэш будет все больше "замусориваться" и по сути это MemLeak, что совсем не есть хорошо... Решение с фабрикой и ContextPreservation самое очевидное, просто хотел узнать, может есть альтернатива фабрике в случае с длительным временем жизни зависящего объекта...

Comment: @kimaman2 если так, то вы тем более идете по правильному пути. Мне в голову другого варианта не приходит.

Comment: Аналогично, кроме фабрики и `using` в голову совсем ничего не приходит...